# trouble about working with material of model visual 3d?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I made a 3d box in code behind.

I want to get color of material (for example, DiffuseMaterial) in a string format
by using  `RayMeshGeometry3DHitTestResult  result1` in mouse left button down:

```
GeometryModel3D result2 = result1.ModelHit as GeometryModel3D;
```

I used:

```
MessageBox.Show(result2.Material.ToString());
```

This does not work!

Thanks alot.

Comment: Which bit doesn't work? result2 is null or color is wrong?

Comment: and you want to get colour, something like `#ffffff`, for all types of material or only `DiffuseMaterial`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get color of the `Brush` used to create `DiffuseMaterial` as a `string` then you need to first check if it is `DiffuseMaterial`, as not all materials need to work of `Brush`, and then you have to check if `Brush` is `SolidColorBrush` as only that will support single color. Something like below should work:

```
DiffuseMaterial material = result2.Material as DiffuseMaterial;
if (material != null)
{
    string brushColor = null;
    var brush = material.Brush as SolidColorBrush;
    if (brush != null)
        brushColor = brush.Color.ToString();
}
```